# How to set IntelliJ IDEA Default Documentation Font Size?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I can change font size of pop-up documentation from right corner(gear icon).

But i have to re-set documentation font for different classes.

Is there any way to set the default documentation font size from preferences?

Comment: Strange... just tried it myself and when I change the font from the documentation pop-up it is used for all classes/projects (IntelliJ 14.1.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the more recent versions of the IDE. E.g. at the **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3** the font size value set in a documentation pop-up can be set only once and will be applied for all classes.